# HTML Table Flashes When Populating It Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

When I got to 'Entity name, number and symbols' in the the course of learning HTML, I decided to apply my basic knowledge of C++ to display display certain symbols depending on the minimum and maximum values entered by users.

I created an HTML form and a table element, wrote a JavaScript function to populate HTML table element with the desired symbols. The result shows that the table only flashes on display.
What might be the issue? See code below:

```
<h2 style="margin-left: 400px;">
  LIST OF HTML ENTITY NUMBERS AND SYMBOLS
</h2>
<form
  action=""
  style="
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 20px;
  "
>
  <label for="inputMin">Minimum Value:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input
    type="text"
    name="minValue"
    id="minValue"
    style="
      font-size: 16px;
      height: 25px;
      border: 1.5px solid black;
      padding: 3px 5px 2px 10px;
    "
  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <label for="inputMax">Maximum Value:</label>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <input
    type="text"
    name="maxValue"
    id="maxValue"
    style="
      font-size: 16px;
      height: 25px;
      border: 1.5px solid black;
      padding: 3px 5px 2px 10px;
    "
  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button
    onclick="genSymb()"
    style="
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bolder;
      color: black;
      background-color: skyblue;
      height: 30px;
      border: 1.5px solid black;
      padding: 3px 5px 2px 5px;
    "
  >
    Generate Symbols
  </button>
</form>

<br /><br /><br />
<table id="entSymTab" style="font-size: 30px; margin: auto;">
  <!-- <th colspan="10">HTML ENTITY NUMBERS AND SYMBOLS</th> -->
</table>

<script>
  function genSymb() {
    // document.getElementById("entSymTab").innerHTML = "";
    var min;
    var max;
    if (
      document.getElementById("minValue").value == "" ||
      document.getElementById("minValue").value == 0
    ) {
      min = 1;
    } else {
      min = document.getElementById("minValue").value;
    }
    if (
      document.getElementById("maxValue").value == "" ||
      document.getElementById("maxValue").value == 0
    ) {
      max = 1;
    } else {
      max = document.getElementById("maxValue").value;
    }

    document.getElementById("entSymTab").innerHTML =
      "<th colspan='10'>HTML ENTITY NUMBERS AND SYMBOLS</th>";

    for (var dr = 1; dr <= Math.ceil((max - min + 1) / 10); dr++) {
      document.getElementById("entSymTab").innerHTML =
        document.getElementById("entSymTab").innerHTML +
        "<tr>" +
        "<td>" +
        (min - 10 + 10 * dr) +
        "<br><br>" +
        ("&#" + (min - 10 + 10 * dr)) +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        (min - 9 + 10 * dr) +
        "<br><br>" +
        ("&#" + (min - 9 + 10 * dr)) +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        (min - 8 + 10 * dr) +
        "<br><br>" +
        ("&#" + (min - 8 + 10 * dr)) +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        (min - 7 + 10 * dr) +
        "<br><br>" +
        ("&#" + (min - 7 + 10 * dr)) +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        (min - 6 + 10 * dr) +
        "<br><br>" +
        ("&#" + (min - 6 + 10 * dr)) +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        (min - 5 + 10 * dr) +
        "<br><br>" +
        ("&#" + (min - 5 + 10 * dr)) +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        (min - 4 + 10 * dr) +
        "<br><br>" +
        ("&#" + (min - 4 + 10 * dr)) +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        (min - 3 + 10 * dr) +
        "<br><br>" +
        ("&#" + (min - 3 + 10 * dr)) +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        (min - 2 + 10 * dr) +
        "<br><br>" +
        ("&#" + (min - 2 + 10 * dr)) +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        (min - 1 + 10 * dr) +
        "<br><br>" +
        ("&#" + (min - 1 + 10 * dr)) +
        "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry, could you clarify what you mean by it "only flashes on display"?

Comment: Meaning it comes up for only less than a second after which it vanishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inside a form element. Whenever you click the button you are submitting the form aka its reloading (flicker) the page. If you don't need a form don't use a form.

Preventing the reload of the page can be done with e.preventDefault(); in the submit function, you will have to pass e to that function from the form though.

### Form (not recommended)

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Twiggeh99/sweh81Lr/22/) with form.
Add to form onSubmit handle, and pass the event to it.

```html
<form onSubmit="genSymb(event)">
```

Change the button type to submit, and remove the function from `onClick`

```html
<button type="submit">
```

Change your `genSymb` function to take the event and prevent the default get request from being fired.

```js
function genSymb(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

### No Form (recommended)

I would just recommend to not use a form because this doesn't seem like you are going to use this data in the backend. To fix your issue all you got to do is change the `<from>...</form>` to `<div>...</div>` or any other suitable tag.
Look in my comment on my post for jsfiddle example.

Other things :
I am not sure why you are using vars. It is a generally bad practice to use them. Use `let` and `const` instead.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Twiggeh99/sweh81Lr/16/ I can't post this into the answer for whatever reason... This will fix your issue, I just renamed the form tag to a div tag

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works like charm. As for the declarations using var, I can't tell you how times I switched between var and let. Perhaps, I'll check the difference between them.

Comment: var is globally scoped, while let and const are block scoped (google that -> "global scope vs block scope" - You should understand their difference when you understand different scopes in js). Use const for values that won't change. Use let for values that will change. (Generally) Never use vars.

Comment: Thanks again. One more thing. I was expecting emojis to start showing up somewhere around &#128512 and beyond. My browser displayed two parallel lines for all the entity numbers in question. Could it be that my browser doesn't support these?

Comment: @BrightJovanni I'm pretty sure js supports emojis. Just put them into the html.https://jsfiddle.net/Twiggeh99/sweh81Lr/24/  I put one into its own div. You can just copy paste the emoji itself, no need for the codes haha

Comment: I see the problem now. It did not display on Google chrome (and IE) even when I visited https://jsfiddle.net/Twiggeh99/sweh81Lr/24/ then I switched to firefox and it worked. Thanks once and again.